# Joining consecutive lines using awk

Tags: string, awk, sed, concatenation, line

How can i join consecutive  lines into a single lines using awk? Actually i have this with my awk command:

```
awk -F "\"*;\"*" '{if (NR!=1) {print $2}}' file.csv
```

*I remove the first line*

```
44895436200043
38401951900014
72204547300054
38929771400013
32116464200027
50744963500014
```

**i want to have this:**

```
44895436200043 38401951900014 72204547300054 38929771400013 32116464200027 50744963500014
```

**csv file**

[image]

Comment: You could use `paste -sd' ' < Input_file` but I feel there should be some dup answer for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to modify your existing awk, so that it prints a horizontal space separated list, instead of words, one per row.

You can replace the `print $2` action in your command, you can do this:

```
awk -F "\"*;\"*" 'NR!=1{u=u s $2; s=" "} END {print u}' file.csv
```

or replace the ORS (output record separator)

```
awk -F "\"*;\"*" -v ORS=" " 'NR!=1{print $2}' file.csv
```

or pipe output to `xargs`:

```
awk -F "\"*;\"*" 'NR!=1{print $2}' file.csv | xargs
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a job for `tr`:

```
# tail -n +2 prints the whole file from line 2 on
# tr '\n' ' ' translates newlines to spaces

tail -n +2 file | tr '\n' ' '
```

With awk, you can achieve this by changing the output record separator to `" "`:

```
# BEGIN{ORS= " "} sets the internal output record separator to a single space
# NR!=1 adds a condition to the default action (print)

awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} NR!=1' file
```

Comment: it's possible to concate your command with my awk command ?

Comment: @Mercer No need to concatenate (pipe) the two awk calls. You can select the field you want to print, e. g.  with `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} NR!=1{print $2}'` file` and you still can set the field separator as you did (or in the `BEGIN` section).